# Why is the performance of ogr methods different on different OS?

Tags: ogr, performance

This question actually comes forth [from an earlier question of mine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73152/python-how-to-speed-up-spatial-search-nearest-point)
.

A short introduction. I was writing a program that performs near analysis and creates buffers for a set of points. On my Linux Ubuntu machine this turned out to be really slow. Hence the earlier mentioned question of mine.

When running the same code on my OSX it was tremendously fast. At least n comparison to the results I was getting on Ubuntu.

Here are my results

```
Method     | OSX            | Linux Ubuntu

ogr buffer | 0:00:01.434389 | 0:01:08.384309

sub string | 0:00:19.714432 | 0:00:10.048649

sorted set | 0:00:01.239999 | 0:00:00.600773
```

So my question really is: why are there such great performance difference with OGR?

```
Specs Mac OSX
Processor 4x2.5 GHz  
Memory 8 GB 1600 MHz

Specs Dell Linux Ubuntu
Processor 8x3.4GHz
Memory 7.8 GB
```

Comment: Well for a start without specs of each machine and the method of timing it's hard to tell much.

Comment: Well, I agree but a second versus 1 minute is quite something. The specs of the machines don't explain that. I will add them anyway for clarity.

Comment: Could be two possible reasons 1- hardware specs 2- gdal version.

Comment: @NathanW Updated my question.

Comment: Hardware could easily explain the difference.  A lot of the newer Apple laptops come with SSDs

Comment: Isn't the data in memory? Can you explain how SSDs influences this?

Comment: SSD have fast read/write times data is in memory until is runs out of room then windows uses pagefile.sys (disk space) MACS do the same...

Comment: You still haven't told us which OGR versions, or how they were compiled, or how you are doing the timing (e.g. the size of the data, the "time clock" source, the code, the compiler options for the tests in each case). I'd personally suspect a compilation option (e.g. debug vs optimised) in either OGR or the test code, but we're all guessing (hence no answer!) unless you're going to show the test case(s)